# Dynamically change background of SCNView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, scenekit, arkit

I am making an iOS app that - in its essential part - receives JPEG images frame by frame via TCP.

Another part of the app has an `ARSCNView`, which background needs to be set dynamically from these frames.

My pseudo code looks like this:

```
while(phase == 1) {
    let bytes = try tcpSocket.read(into: &jpegData)
    sceneView.scene.background.contents = UIImage(data: jpegData)

    // or the other way

    let bgempty = backgroundImage == nil
    backgroundImage = UIImage(data: jpegData)
    if(bgempty) {
       sceneView.scene.background.contents = backgroundImage
    }
}
```

That's pretty much it. Either way, this loop creates a memory leak. Same when I use `CGImage`

How would you assign an ever changing background to `ARSCNView`, avoiding memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be using [`autoreleasepool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) block. This could ensure the footprint of memory keeps minimum. The loop you use takes a lot of device’s memory, to optimize this code you could add autorelease pool as follows:

```
while(phase == 1) {
    autoreleasepool {
        let bytes = try tcpSocket.read(into: &jpegData)
        sceneView.scene.background.contents = UIImage(data: jpegData)

        // or the other way

        let bgempty = backgroundImage == nil
        backgroundImage = UIImage(data: jpegData)
        if(bgempty) {
            sceneView.scene.background.contents = backgroundImage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! So simple! I was wondering of these deallocation functions in Swift